# What's the difference between 'embedded' and 'rooted'?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to figure out the answer to a Proficiency C2 question:

> Thus, having a meal first thing in the morning was .........in necessity, and was no longer associated with social status along.

Does embedded or rooted go in the missing space and why?

Comment: _Root_ has a historical meaning, which is why _rooted in_ means 'started from'.

Answer (score 2):

"rooted", as having grown from, like a plant, would be correct.
"embedded", rather, suggests deliberate placement within another thing.